# Regex to match if string is exactly as defined

Tags: c#, regex

How can I check that the string is in correct format. I want the string to compare and pass only if matches exactly. Following are the correct formats :

0.#

0.##

0.###

0.####

0.#####

The hash (#) after the dot (.) can be upto 10 characters but it should only have 0.# nothing else is allowed.

Can someone please guide me how can I validate a string of this type ?

Comment: use `^` and `$` to specify the expected start of the string and end of the string, respectively, when you need exact matches

Comment: `^0.\d{1,10}$` ?

Comment: This URL below will help you understand Regex.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/simple-regex-tricks-for-beginners-3acb3fa257cb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im Regular Expression the carret (^) represent start-of-line and the ($) represents end-of-line (or before newline).

A regex with an exact match is just what you want enclosed by ^ and $. But you must ensure that special regular expression characters are quoted. For example the regex

```
^Hello World$
```

would match exactly on the String "Hello World" and nothing else.

You also can use numbers directly. You need to escape the dot "." as a dot in a regular expression means any character except newline. You escape a character by adding a backslash.

Next you should know about quantifiers. The usually ones are

- ```
  -> 0 or many
  ```

- ```
  -> 1 or many
  ```

{n}   -> exactly n times
{n,}  -> at least n times
{n,m} -> n to m times

So you can write:

```
^0\.#{1,10}$
```

If you use a normal string in C# with quotations (") you must use two backslashes

```
^0\\.#{1,10}$
```